# Why does =default on operator= compile when there is a const member?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;
private:
  const int i = 0;
};
```

Why is `=default` allowed there? It compiles without errors. I would think that `=default` should fail since it's not possibly to assign into the `const` variable?

What actually is happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When the function cannot be generated (as is the case), `= default` will generate it as `= delete`d instead. If you try to use that assignment operator your compiler should [produce an error](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=273e22dfdbf1660d1aac1c5c67d45d02).